# c++ Search Number for Number

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++, and was presented this problem and am really not sure how to proceed.

I'd be given a number from 0-999, and I'm trying to determine whether or not the digits of 1, 4, or 7 appear in that number.

I've tried using `find_first_of()`, but am having many errors.

Here's my code so far:

```
double ctemp;  
cin >> ctemp;  
if(ctemp.find_first_of(1)==-1 && ctemp.find_first_of(4)==-1 && ctemp.find_first_of(7)==-1) 
{
    cout << "Found digits 1, 4, 7.\n";
}
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

`11:18: error: request for member 'find_first_of' in 'ctemp', which is of non-class type 'double'`

I tried changing the variable types to string but it made even more errors and whatnot. Does anyone have any ways to make the search for the digits any easier?

Comment: You need to load your number into a `std::string` or convert your double to it. (But if it's integer, use int and not double)

Comment: A string is a sequence of characters. A number is not a sequence of digits. If you read into a string, you want `find_first_of('1')`.

Comment: How about read the error message? This one is especially clear.

Comment: Do you need to check if *all* the digits 1, 4 and 7 appear in the number? Or just one/two of them?

Answer (score 3):

If your number is integer between 0 and 999, you should be using `int` instead of `double`.

One way to solve this is by taking the modulo of 10 until there's nothing left. In this way, you will look at the smallest digit of the number (right-to-left).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_digit_in_number(int digit, int number)
{
    int i;

    if (number < 0) number = -number; /* see Cthulhu's comment */

    while (number != 0) {
        i = number % 10;
        if (i == digit) return 1;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("3 in 12345: %d \n", is_digit_in_number(3, 12345));
    printf("9 in -12345: %d \n", is_digit_in_number(9, -12345));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It wont work for second example (although it will accidentally report correct result) because (as idiotic as it is) `a % b` <= 0 for `a` < 0 in c++

Comment: Fixed, thanks! Some extra characters to placate the Javascript and express my gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

you have to enter your number in the form of `string` or later convert it into a `string` because `find_first_of()` works on `string`.
It returns position of the first character that matches.
If no matches are found, the function returns `string::npos` (= -1).

```
string ctemp;  
cin >> ctemp;  
    if(ctemp.find_first_of('1')!=string::npos && ctemp.find_first_of('4')!=string::npos&& ctemp.find_first_of('7')!=string::npos) 
{
    cout << "Found digits 1, 4, 7.\n";
}
```

Comment: You mention `string::npos` and then don't use it in your code example.

Comment: because this constant is defined with a value of -1 so -1 is shorter to write in code.

Comment: Shorter doesn't necessarily mean better.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cast your number into a string and search that for the digits.

```
std::string str = std::to_string(ctemp);
if(str.find_first_of('1')!=std::string::npos || 
   str.find_first_of('4')!=std::string::npos || 
   str.find_first_of('7')!=std::string::npos) 
{
    cout << "Found digits 1, 4, 7.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search an integer if it contains 1, 4, or 7 by checking the last digit (the 1's digit) if it's 1, 4, or 7, and removing that digit to check the next one.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    bool numberFound = false;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;

    while (a != 0)
    {
        // determines if the last number is either 1, 4, or 7
        switch (a % 10)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "1 is in the number." << endl;
            numberFound = true;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "4 is in the number." << endl;
            numberFound = true;
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << "7 is in the number." << endl;
            numberFound = true;
            break;
        default:
            numberFound = false;
            break;
        }
        a /= 10; // removes the last digit so the next one can be checked
    }
    if (!numberFound)
        cout << "1, 4, or 7 isn't in the number." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```